# Explorer window like address bar

Tags: c#, winforms

The file system explorer window in Vista and Windows 7 has a bar at the top of the window where one can type in the address to look at. When you leave the field it turns from being a text edit field to a field with buttons and drop down menus that can be used for navigating.

Are there any existing components like this? How can one go about building this type of component?

Comment: Such a control is called breadcrumb control. You will find several vendors offering commercial controls similar to the one in Explorer: > [**Breadcrumb controls](http://www.google.de/search?q=windows+forms+breadcrumb+control&btnG=Suche&hl=de&sa=2)**

Answer (score 0):

Spy++ shows it to be a ToolbarWindow32. So it is just a toolbar but functionality seems to have been added to it.